# How to convert access DB to ERD

Tags: ms-access, erd

I need to create an ERD of my access database relationships & tables, Do I need to create it manually or is it possible to upload the access file to some website/software that makes it manually?

Comment: For what reason would you not use the built in relationships diagram tool?

Answer (score 0):

Commercial products like SAP PowerDesigner, ERWin, [DeZign](https://www.datanamic.com/dezign/buy.html) can reverse databases to ER diagrams. Most of them have trial versions, they may be useful if it's one time task.

You can also look for open source products like [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/). Dia cannot reverse databases by itself, but there are a lot of plugins for it like [AutoDia](http://www.aarontrevena.co.uk/opensource/autodia/), they may help with reverse engineering.